# PHP post a specific query result into another PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I have a problem with a PHP/SQL project I'm writing. It is basically a database of books, every book has its owner data. I set up a query to retrieve every book matching the query; what I want to do is being able to select one of the results, post its data to another PHP file (which will send a mail to the owner of the book). I wrote the code like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE parameter LIKE '%$value%' OR parameter LIKE '$value%' OR parameter LIKE '%$value'"; $result=mysql_query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0; while ($i < $num) {
$attribute = mysql_result($result,$i,"attribute");
$mail = mysql_result($result,$i,"mail");
echo "
<form action=\"mailform.php\" method=\"post\"/><table border=\"1\">
<tr><
<td>$attribute</td>
<td>$mail</td>
<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/></form></td>
</tr>
</table>
";
$i++;
}
```

The query is working, I get results.
The mailform.php is set up this way

```
<?php
$mail = $_POST['$mail'];
?>
```

When I click on the submit button i am redirected to mailform.php but I get this error:
Notice: Undefined index: $emailproprietario

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Remember, you should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I can't see any code that mentions `emailproprietario` as an array index. Would you add it?

Comment: first, modify your syntax to use `mysqli_` vs `mysql_`, you are leaving you and your users open to massive vulnerabilities. second, if you want to access the values after the page has rendered (like at submit), you need to store the values in a more permanent way ... a `$_SESSION` variable, or an `<input type="hidden" />`

Comment: Your form seems to contain invalid HTML: `<tr><`. You are opening the form before opening the table, but closing the form before closing the table. You'll want to include your data in form fields rather than table cells. Check out [My First HTML Form - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form).

Comment: Not even sure why this get upvotes. Cleary OP did not research anything at all.. His form does not even contain inputs

Comment: where is your input filed inside the form

Comment: Voting to put on hold for the time being. OP, if this does get put on hold, if you can add the code we need to see, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is badly formed - the table spans the form instead of being nested, there is an extra, unmatched angle bracket, the form tag is self-closed and your not sending any data from the form. Consider:

```
<form action=\"mailform.php\" method=\"post\">
  <table border=\"1\">
    <tr><td>$attribute</td>
        <td>$mail</td>
        <td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"attribute\" value=\"$attribute\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mail\" value=\"$mail\">
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, you have been very kind, thanks! I'm sorry if this was a stupid question (as someone stated in comments), but I am a newbie, I don't have a great experience in programming but I really need to do this, and I'm trying very hard to.